# Warning cones & non editable Text Fields on JPopupMenu in Java Applet

Tags: java, swing, applet

I have a Java applet with a JPopupMenu inside of it. The JPopupMenu itself has a few JTextfields for input. When I test my applet inside of Eclipse, the popup menu and Text Fields work perfectly.

However when the Applet it deployed to the web, I get the issue of all the JTextFields being un-editable. They're just greyed out with no carrot. The menus also have tiny warning cones next to them (they light up when you scroll over them but that's it)

Example:

[image: warning cones!]
[image]

JTextField there has an initial value of 123, can be clicked on but to carrot appears and is not editable.

Is this a permissions issue or something else entirely? My applet is not Signed but all my security settings are at minimum. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is a security warning to the user that the dialog/popup belongs to the applet.

Without this you could "trick" the user by creating similar popups and dialogs to those of your browser or system popups and ask for sensitive information.

Comment: That's what I thought. But what about my text fields? Does it disable them as a precaution too, or what?

Comment: I would doubt that. Can you post code and screenshot for the disabled text fields?

Comment: I posted a screenshot of it, not sure how helpful it is. I'll work on an SSCE of the problem.

Comment: +1  To remove the warnings, digitally sign the applet and declare `all-permissions`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about warnings. I tried to make an SSCE of the problem, but it worked. So there must be something special about my JPopupMenu. It's a gigantic menu that dynamically rebuilt multiple times so I've got some work ahead of me to find the issue